# Upload the Graph font in the aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

While generating the graph using canvas-prebuilt, the font family is getting loaded. How can I upload it using serverless in AWS?

This is using canvas-prebuilt version `1.6.5-prerelease.1` and `chartjs-node-canvas` version 1.1.6. I am updating the `chartjs-node-canvas` module  `index.ts` file to `registerFont()`. I am using `https://github.com/techfu-io/chartjs-lambda/tree/master/node_modules` code as the Lambda invoker.

The error I am receiving is:

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

I have font and passing the path:

```
registerFont('./fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf', { family: 'Montserrat', weight: '900' });
```

where my font is stored.

[image: Result image base64 data]

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the path to the configuration file `font.conf`:

```js
// Before connecting fonts
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH = __dirname
```

You also need the configuration file `font.conf` itself (placed next to `package.json`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>./fonts</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

And of course you will need fonts. Put them in a folder `fonts` (next to `package.json`)

You can now register fonts. But do not forget to set `FONTCONFIG_PATH` environment variable before this.

```js
registerFont('./fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf', { family: 'Montserrat', weight: '900' })
```

Comment: I was having trouble with Asap working on my mac but not on a linux server. Making sure the fonts weren't WOFF but TTF, setup like this ^ and ignoring weight seemed to help. So rather than setup 'Asap' '700' the font was just 'Asap Bold' 'regular'